# php mvc view load mutiple times

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have been working on a custom made MVC in PHP. It's made from scratch, but i have encountered a problem:

My view controller is quite simple one, but when I call method `products()`, it includes the view products infinite times. What could be causing this?

```
//this is the autoload method in view controller
public function __autoload() 
{
    for ( $i=0; $i < count($this->include_files); $i++ )
    {
        require 'views/' . $this->include_files[$i] . '.php';
    }
}
//this is the products method in view controller
public function products()
{
    $this->include_files[0]='header';
    $this->include_files[1]='navigation';
    $this->include_files[2]='products';
    $this->include_files[3]='footer';
    $this->__autoload();
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please write the output of `var_dump($this->include_files)` before the `for` loop. By the way , why not using `foreach` ?

Comment: this is the out put @OfirBaruch 
array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "header" [1]=> string(10) "navigation" [2]=> string(8) "products" [3]=> string(6) "footer" }

Comment: @engr.waqas , i edited the question a bit. Please make sure that i did not make any mistakes "in translation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @ofir Baruch 
your question had the answer,its working fine,when i used foreach

```
public function __autoload() {
        foreach($this->include_files as $file)
        require 'views/'.$file. '.php';
    }
```